# Teamcity Time Out or Unrecognized URL connecting to VSO

Tags: git, version-control, teamcity, azure-devops

I am completely unable to connect Team City to our VSO git repository - After some time I get one of the following errors:

```
List remote refs failed: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Cannot create a project using the specified URL. The URL is not recognized.
```

[image: Error Message]

I am able to git clone the repository from the same machine that TeamCity is installed on.

I have enabled alternative credentials on my account and am using that set of credentials to connect to Team City.

URL Format I've been following:

https://{CompanyName}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/{RepoName}

There are no spaces in the Company Name or the Repo Name as well.

Has anyone else run into this issue or have any further troubleshooting steps I can take to figure this out?

---

Removing /_git/{ProjectName} as per Dan's suggestion gives me the same error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `_git/XXX` part from your URL, TeamCity will know how to retrieve the repo using an url like: `https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection`. Check [this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2014/09/teamcity-and-visual-studio-online-source-control/) post for more details.

Comment: Hi Dan, Please see my edited OP - Same issue for some reason.

Comment: @Matt What TeamCity version are you using?

Comment: TeamCity Professional 9.1.4 (build 37293)

Comment: I don't know what to say, I just tried it again with the full path /_git/{ProjectName} and it seems to be going through now... Scanning for VCS repositories.

Comment: I think you should file a bug, since even with your full `URL` it should work based on the linked page from my answer.